# How to use vuforia and unity to create a ppt or pdf reader for an AR app

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to use vuforia and unity to create a ppt or pdf reader.But I am stuck with the problem that I don't know how to display a ppt or pdf in unity. Besides, I want to use some gestures to slide these ppt.. Is there any package which I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my solution is to use UIImage to display these slides. So at first, I need to convert these slides to image.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to use some libraries to convert your PDF or PPT files to images (slideshows) and then to display them on screen simply by using unity integrated UI system. Then you could use some scripts based on input detection to change images (slides).

Comment: I just come up with an idea that can I try to use the webView or webKit? Because we can upload our ppt and pdf to the server? And I have tried to search for some packages which support the web view. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @HanslenChen never used webView inside Unity so I can't say much about it but it should do the trick too (even if it would require a constant internet connection). Also make sure the Unity input will be correctly provided to the webView :)